# Why are my reply-to addresses not whats displayed in RMM?

Tags: marketing-cloud, reply-mail-management

I have setup my RMM so that the "reply subdomain" is my SAP domain (mailer.domain.com), and my "email reply address" is reply@mailer.domain.com.

When I send an email to myself, the reply to address looks like `reply-ff60137471-51_HTML-535774-500009153-1@mailer.domain.com`.

Can anyone explain why this is? Also can someone explain what the DNS record redirect does? When responding to the address above I can confirm the response is forwarded to the remaining responses email set in RMM.

Edit: The sender profiles used do not have custom settings enabled.

Edit 2: Included screenshot of RMM config
[image: RMM Setup Screen]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason your reply address is not shown as the simplified address you have set (`reply@mailer.domain.com`) in the email client is because the crazy numbers and letters, etc are actually containing the context of the original email for the Reply Mail Management (RMM) system in SFMC to correctly identify and correlate this reply in order to follow the associated rulesets for it. The final place this reply will end up is the address you specified after being processed in the RMM.

The process regarding RMM is as follows below:

**Step 1**: Email is sent and ReplyTo Address is created and sent in email header. This ReplyTo address is a mixture of the information you put inside of the RMM / Sender Profile and an encrypted string appended on to include context.

**Step 2**: When someone hits reply on the email, the replyTo address is filled into the 'To' field. This address is the one that includes the crazy numbers and letters. The 'Name' or 'Alias' of the replyto will be exactly as defined though, only the address will be altered.

**Step 3**: Once the reply is sent. This reply is then sent into the SFMC RMM system to be processed. After being processed, if it passes all parameters, the email is then forwarded to your designated reply address inside the RMM/Sender Profile.

To avoid this, you would have to avoid the RMM system and instead do a direct forward to that address. But do note that this removes all auto unsub and other 'benefits' that RMM allows you and instead would just be a direct reply to your email.

Comment: I'm not really sure I follow here, I get that the `Routing Address for Remaining Replies` is the final address the email will end up on. Have a look at the screenshot in the original post. What are the details "Reply Address Definition" used for?

Comment: Also the correct "Name" is in fact shown, I suspect this comes from the Reply Address Definition. It's just the address that doesn't correlate, while I get the use of those fuzzy numbers and characters and how it does the matching etc, what is the purpose of `Email Reply Address` if it's not used?

Comment: The Email Reply Address is where it goes after the RMM does it. Routing address is a default for all those that fall out and do not fit into any rules in RMM.  Kinda think of it as a default replyto.  I am gonna edit my answer and hopefully further clarify

Comment: We don't have Enterprise RMM enabled, so we don't have any rules setup that you're referring to aside from the reply filters. If the email doesn't contain unsub or auto-repsponse will it use the "Email Reply Address" or the "Routing Address for Remaining Replies"?

Comment: Wait I think I'm just being super silly here... am I right that the `Email Reply Address` is used for responses by RMM to the Subscriber?

Comment: The `Email Reply Address` is the final Email that will receive the replies. Not what is displayed in the replyTo address.

Comment: @Gortonington do you know of a way to make sure that emails to reply@mailer.domain.com don't get lost in cyberspace? We're having an issue where people are replying directly to the reply email address, but not responding to the generated address. So they are literally pulling up a new email and typing reply@mailer.domain.com and sending the email, and those are getting lost. I am wondering if it's an issue with SAP not being fully configured or perhaps if we self-host they can do our own forwarding...

Comment: @Gortonington I still don't follow here. It looks like the odd HTML characters aren't showing up in any provider except Outlook desktop. Is there a way to ensure that they don't show there either?